# Alternative to Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Is there a complex / real analysis book that is *as good* as Rudin (rigorous, readable, etc) but not as *hard*?    By that I mean shorter, and it's more likely that I'll finish it.  I understand the basics of measure theory so far.

Comment: Real Analysis by Gerald Folland

Comment: Try Elementary Analysis: the Theory of Calculus, by Ross.

Comment: @RaziehNoori: I agree, but would like to mention that complex analysis is not covered by Folland.

Comment: @Kahler there's math objects named after you.